# How to make a slideshow where the user can use navigation buttons, no timers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm trying to create a slideshow for my website, where it doesn't use any timer of a kind because that's what I have right now, but I want the user to be able to use the navigational buttons. I've been trying to google it but everything I come across seems really complex and I can't get a hold of it. So was wondering if anyone here would be willing to explain how I would do that.

Here a picture of the situation is and how I'm gonna use it. It's an overlay.

[image]

Comment: More details will be required..Do you intend to use a framework to solve this problem? Maybe you should try writing some code, see how far you can get. Off the top of my head, you can adjust the time set for a carousel to shift images, so you have full control.

Comment: Creating a slide show isn't super easy, you need to stack all the images on top of each other, then change position of them as they move "right?"  You also want to define the height of the container since the size of the container will be determined by the image which has position:relative.

Answer (score 0):

does you website support bootstrap if its is you can use bootstrap Carousel slider.
you can stop auto slide by setting the property

```
  $('.carousel').carousel({
          interval: false
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

### USE THIS CODE FOR NAVIGATION PANEL WITH DROP DOWN FUNCTION

```css
body
{
/*background: url (whatever you want to use) no-repeat; */
background-size: cover;
font-family: Arial;
color: white
}
ul
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style: none;
}
ul li
{
float: left;
width: 200px;
height: 40px;
background-color: black;
opacity: .8;
line-height: 40px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
}
ul li a
{
color: white;
display: block;
}
ul li a:hover
{
background color:green;
}
ul li ul li
{
display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul li
{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link href ='style.css' rel= 'stylesheet' >
<ul>
<li><a>Home</a></li>
<li><a>About</a>
<ul>
<li><a>First</a></li>
<li><a>Second</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a>Things to do</a>
<ul>
<li><a>First</a></li>
<li><a>Second</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a>Contact</a>
<ul>
<li><a>First</a></li>
<li><a>Second</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a>News</a>
<ul>
<li><a>First</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</html>
```